# Supply a non-anonymous function to Jquery: success + additional confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can not get my JQUERY .ajax request to accept a function (*non-anonymous*) to the success condition.

The reason why I am choosing to not use an anonymous function (which I know will work) is because I think they are more difficult to debug and read. I also read that functions should be broken out as a good design and code-reuse factor.

```
$.ajax({
    url: total_url, 
    type: "POST",
    data: {already_voted: already_seen},
    success: ajax_get_data_success(data),
    error:  function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('XHR ERROR ' + XMLHttpRequest.status);
            }
```

My success function is NEVER sent the DATA object?

```
My error is Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

Obviously data has not been defined, it is  supposed to accept the DATA  upon success.

Here is my function for the success case:

```
function ajax_get_data_success(data)
{

        try{
                 console.log(data.id);
                  console.log("Recieved" + data.id);
                  update_seen_state(data.id);
                  update_ui();
    }catch(err)
    {
        console.log("Ajax_get_data", err);

    }

}
```

** Update: As suggested I removed the extra paramaters and the call worked. However, this has sent me through the rabbit hole further as to how calls are made in JQUERY.

**Per the JQUERY API, the success case takes only 3 paramater, and the error case takes 3 paramaters.  From a programatic standpoint, that means when a successful ajax connection has been made, their code will pass to MY FUNCTION only 3 paramaters.

Wouldn't Javascript get confused if I increased the number of parameters that were allowed to be passed to the function?

Answer (score 2):

The error is self explanatory. You are using the variable `data` which is not defined above. The javascript engine don't know what `data` is !

In your case for your ajax success event handler, just specify your function name, no need to specify the param there. Just have it in your function definition (which you already have).

This should work.

```
success: ajax_get_data_success,
```

**EDIT :** *As per the comment*

> What if I wanted to pass it additional arguments?

You can do this

```
var myArray = ["My","Custom","Array","I want to pass"];
$.ajax({
    url: total_url, 
    type: "POST",
    data: {already_voted: already_seen},
    success:function (ajaxResponse) { ajax_get_data_success(myArray , ajaxResponse) }
    });
```

and now your method accepts 2 params

```
function ajax_get_data_success(yourData,ajaxResponseData)
{
  console.log(yourData);
  console.log(ajaxResponseData);
}
```

Well, now you are using again an an anonymous method in your success event.

Comment: Why does this work. What if I wanted to pass it additional arguments?

Comment: What additional argument you want to pass ?

Comment: I have an array called items;

Comment: @Vic wrap the function call in an anonymous function.

Comment: Pointy: I apologize for being so dense. The developers of JQUERY through their api said their success, and failure will take at MOST 1, and 3 possible elements.   What this means is their code will always past either 1 or 3 paramaters. If I wrap it won't i lose the other items passed.

Comment: If you want those, you can still access and pass those to your method like `success: function (a, b, ajaxResponse) { myCallback(a, b, myArray, ajaxResponse) }`. Make sure to add 2 more params to your method to accept those now.